# ¿Cómo mostrar un modal condicionalmente en React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Estoy intentando mostrar un modal de manera condicional. Este condicional se muestra cuando se realiza el registro, a modo informativo para informar de si el registro se ha realizado correctamente o no.

Este modal puede ser de dos formas, dependiendo de si ha ido bien o mal:

```
                         {(response.status === "OK") ?
                            (<ModalMsg
                                isVisible={modalIsVisible}
                                title='¡Registro correcto!'
                                description='Se ha enviado un correo con el identificador empresarial.'
                                iconName='checkmark-circle'
                                headerColor='#50C878'
                                textButton='OK'
                                colorButton='#50C878'
                            />)
                            :
                            (<ModalMsg
                                isVisible={modalIsVisible}
                                title='Registro incorrecto'
                                description={response.message}
                                iconName='close-circle'
                                headerColor='#FA5F55'
                                textButton='OK'
                                colorButton='#FA5F55'
                            />)
                        }
```

El valor que se evalua lo saco del un contexto que tengo creado:

```
const { signUp, response } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Cuando hago la llamada al endpoint que crea el registro, veo como el status cambia, pero no se muestra el modal.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Revisaste si cambias el valor del estado `modalIsVisible`?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaria poner directamente el valor de la propiedad `isVisible` que corresponde a cada condición. Por ejemplo,

```
<ModalMsg
   isVisible=true
   title='¡Registro correcto!'
   description='Se ha enviado un correo con el identificador empresarial.'
   iconName='checkmark-circle'
   headerColor='#50C878'
   textButton='OK'
   colorButton='#50C878'
/>
```

Esto simplifica el código y te evita la declaración innecesaria de variables.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).